# После обновления Intellig IDEA в консоли слева исчез крестик закрытия работы кода

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Обновил Intellij IDEA. После запуска кода, в консольной строке исчез крестик закрытия программы слева. Это что-то у меня криво установилось или это они обновили ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня то же, что и на картинке, Win10/IDEA 2018.2.

Comment: @AntonSorokin значит поменяли в обновлении. А так удобно было.. Зачем надо было убирать его?

Comment: Найдите changelog версии и посмотрите что с ним случилось.

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь они его заменили на exit, третий значёк снизу

Comment: так прикол в том, что эта кнопка не активна

Comment: Просто я на оконном приложении проверял, у меня кнопка exit работала